# How do I determine which params are missing for InvalidOAuthParametersError?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, google-chrome-extension

I'm using [GAE's Python oauth api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/functions) to get the current user. But I'm getting `InvalidOAuthParametersError`. 
How do I determine which param is missing/invalid?

I'm authenticating using [Google Chrome oauth library](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html) (it's for an extension).

Comment: You might want to add more details as to what exactly you're doing that's failing (what method call?).

Comment: Please remove this post. I've posted a more specific question regarding AppEngine's oauth api. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378345/appengine-oauth-api-not-working-with-multiple-sign-in)